# ¿Diferencia entre usar addChildViewController o solo addSubview?

Tags: ios, swift

He creado un viewController en el storyboard. Este viewController lo meto dentro de otro principal con self.view.addSubview y lo muestro en una coordenada x,y. Todo perfecto
pero he visto otros casos donde ademas se usa addChildViewController

¿ Cuando debo usar addChildViewController y cuando no ?

Comment: Hola Popularfan. Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Aqui resolvemos dudas concretas como errores durante  programacion. Para tu pregunta, busca informacion en la documentacion o en guias. Para más informacion, lee [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, Hay alguna documentación o guía en castellano donde pueda resolver esta duda ?

Comment: No lo se. Pero google es tu amigo. Para dudas como esta tambien puedes usar el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).  Un saludo y suerte en la busqueda.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se ha hecho en **stackoverflow.com** [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438847/difference-between-addchildviewcontroller-and-addsubview). Está en inglés, pero se entiende bastante bien. No obstante, siempre puedes ayudarte con el [traductor](https://translate.google.es/).
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Yo te puedo contestar es muy fácil.

**addSubview**: Es un método para añadir una `View` a otra `View` como hijas.

**addChildViewController**: Es un método para añadir `ViewController` a otros `ViewController` como hijos como su nombre indica.

Existe una gran diferencia. Cuando tu por ejemplo instancias algo así:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
```

Estás llamando al metodo `init()` pero no se está iniciando la vista o el `loadView`

Entonces estás creando un `ViewController` vacio.

La forma de hacer lo correctamente es la siguiente:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
parentViewController.addChildViewController(viewController) //Aquí se forma la vista y ya puedes acceder a viewController.view y no es nil
parentViewController.view.addSubview(viewController.view) //Aquí añades la vista
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación, pero tenia entendido que ademas había otra diferencia a nivel de interacción con el usuario

Comment: Hombre, como que si no lo haces no carga la vista jajaja la diferencia es que el usuario ni interactua ni nada jajajaja